# Type error: Too few arguments to function createRoute(), 0 passed and exactly 3 expected in RoutesController

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, arguments, swagger

I'm working on `Laravel` 5.6,

I'm creating a function that receives three parameters `($name_route, $description_route, $photo_route)` that I would like to be inserted on table Route, but I'm having the following error that can't explain:

`"Type error: Too few arguments to function App\\Http\\Controllers\\RoutesController::createRoute(), 0 passed and exactly 3 expected in RoutesController.php (64)"`

What am I doing wrong if I'm passing those three variables? I'm testing using `Swagger`.

Here's how I'm setting in my routes file `(routes.php)`:

```
 /** ***********************************************************
 *  Logged user can create a route
 * ************************************************************
 * @SWG\Post(
 *      tags={"Routes"},
 *      path="/api/v1/routes/route/create",
 *      summary="Logged user can create a route",
 *      @SWG\Parameter(ref="#/parameters/Accept"),
 *      @SWG\Parameter(ref="#/parameters/apikey"),
 *      @SWG\Parameter(ref="#/parameters/Language"),
 *      @SWG\Parameter(ref="#/parameters/Authorization"),
 *      @SWG\Parameter(name="name", in="path", type="string"),
 *      @SWG\Parameter(name="description", in="path", type="string"),
 *      @SWG\Parameter(name="photo", in="path", type="string"),
 *      @SWG\Response(response=HTTP_CODE_200_OK, description="Routes", 
        @SWG\Schema(ref="#/definitions/RouteDetail")),
 * )
 */
Route::post('/route/create', 'RoutesController@createRoute')->middleware('auth:api');
```

And my controller:

```
 /**
 * @param $name_route
 * @param $description_route
 * @param $photo_route
 */
public function createRoute($name_route, $description_route, $photo_route)
{
    $route = new Route();

    $route->user_id = $this->input($this->user()->id);
    $route->name = $this->input($name_route);
    $route->description = $this->input($description_route);
    $route->photo = $this->input($photo_route);

    $route->save();
}
```

Comment: Why dont you specify parameter inside route: `Route::post('/route/create/{name}/{description}/{photo}', 'RoutesController@createRoute')`

Comment: I did, but now I'm facing this problem: "Call to a member function save() on boolean" thanks a lot for your answer

Comment: I've just solved the second problem with this: $user = Auth::user();

        $route = new Route();
        $route->user_id = $this->user()->id;
        $route->name = $name_route;
        $route->description = $description_route;
        $route->photo = $photo_route;

        $user->routes()->save($route);